# How to return locked keystore instance after decode from base64?

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode, keystore

I'm writing **JAVA** project related to *keystores* and *certificates*. I wrote a methods to; *generate dynamic keystore* when provide set of certificate, *encode keystore* to **Base64** encoding string, *decode* **Base64** string to **PKCS12** keystore instance. 
When *generate* the keystore, I provide a password to it as follows.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(null, null);

keystore.setCertificateEntry(aliasName1, certificate1);
keystore.setCertificateEntry(aliasName2, certificate2);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
char[] keystorePasswordAsCharArray = keystorePassword.toCharArray();

OutputStream outputStreamForEncode = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(byteArrayOutputStream);
keystore.store(outputStreamForEncode, keystorePasswordAsCharArray); 
.
.
.
```

After that, when *decode* also I provide a password to it as follows.

```
KeyStore outputKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64EncodedKeystoreString.getBytes());
InputStream inputStreamForDecode = Base64.getDecoder().wrap(inputStream);

char[] keystorePasswordAsCharArray = keystorePassword.toCharArray();
outputKeystore.load(inputStreamForDecode, keystorePasswordAsCharArray);
```

Then the output keystore instance is **unlocked** and I return the instance from method.

But I want to return the **locked** keystore instance. How can I do that?

---

- ***EDITED***

---

Comment: can you share a minimal, reproducible example? It's hard to understand your question with the above 3 lines of code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example